# How to read last word or last line in DocumenListener

Tags: java, swing, javax.swing.text

I implement DocumentListener for JEditorPane ( need help with method insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) ). How to read last word or last line (lines are separated by '\n' and words are separated by ' ' ) ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a JEditorPane. JEditorPanes are for displaying HTML. HTML doesn't use the concept of lines. You just add text and the HTML will wrap the text when ever it is appropriate. If you want to force a new line then you use a <br> tag. I would think you should be using a JTextArea or a JTextPane to work with regular text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last line in your JEditorPane, split the text in the editor on `\n` as shown below:

```
String text = editor.getText();
String[] lines = text.split("\n");
String lastLine = lines[lines.length-1];
System.out.println("Last line: " + lastLine);
```

Similarly, to get the last word, split the last line on space.

Comment: Not a very efficient solution especially for large files. You should take advantage of the Docuement structure because the text has already been parsed into line.

Answer (score 3):

Utilities class can be used with formatted content e.g. html

```
public static final int getWordStart(JTextComponent c, int offs) throws BadLocationException 
public static final int getWordEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs) throws BadLocationException
```

Comment: +1, much better solution that will work on any size file. All you need to know is document.getLength() and you can get the offsets of the last word. Then you use document.getText(...) method to get the word. And if you want the last line you can use the getLineStart/End methods to get the offsets.